# How to check/enable the full speed of SATA drive/port?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

Recently I've got mSata SSD and install it in my laptop.

According to the specification of this SSD, the read rate is approximately 450 MB/s.
I tested the read rate (in menu `Application > Accessories > Disks > Benchmark Disk`) and got the smaller value 280 MB/s.

Digging around I got the following result:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
```

**How can I enable the full speed 6.0 Gb/s?**

OR

<s>**How can I check the maximal speed of SSD/port/something?**</s>

**How can I identify the device (SSD/port/something) reducing the resulting speed?**

Thank you in advance!

*Additional information:*

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep SATA
Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0

$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep speed
   *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
   *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
   *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)

$ lspci | grep SATA
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)

$ dmesg | grep ata
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000baf9f000-0x00000000baffefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] Memory: 7968868K/8242108K available (12300K kernel code, 2481K rwdata, 4012K rodata, 2368K init, 2372K bss, 273240K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.122082] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    1.186115] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 18432k
[    1.448965] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQBC data block query control method not found
[    1.489423] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd0618000 port 0xd0618100 irq 26
[    1.489478] ata2: DUMMY
[    1.489508] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd0618000 port 0xd0618200 irq 26
[    1.489555] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xd0618000 port 0xd0618280 irq 26
[    1.490239] ata5: DUMMY
[    1.490268] ata6: DUMMY
[    1.802539] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.802567] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.802591] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    1.802676] ata3.00: ATA-11: MT-64, 1.74.00, max UDMA/133
[    1.802685] ata3.00: 125045424 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.802787] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.811416] ata4.00: ATAPI: TSSTcorp DVD+/-RW SN-208BB, D300, max UDMA/100
[    1.813156] ata1.00: ATA-8: ST9750420AS, 0005DEM1, max UDMA/133
[    1.813160] ata1.00: 1465149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[    1.815466] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.850643] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    8.712553] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.973968] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   11.987641] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   12.056330] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

UPD:

```
$ dmesg | grep AHCI
[    1.471403] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0xd impl SATA mode
```

Comment: Do you have the SATA mode in BIOS set to IDE or AHCI?

Comment: @dobey
I set AHCI mode. And `lspci | grep SATA` confirm this (see above).

Comment: You should check that the controller also has support for the 6Gbps specs. Just google it, or check the PC manual support page. Also, keep in mind that advertised speeds are usually theoretical throughputs, which are next to impossible to obtain in real world.

Comment: @mikewhatever Ok, I'll try. But I'm interesting in "How can I check the maximal speed of SSD/port/controller?" using software of Ubuntu/Linux. Or it is not possible?

Comment: Check the output of dmesg again. It reports sata link capabilities of 1.5 and 3.0 Gbps. It seems to be enough info, not sure what else it should do.

Comment: @mikewhatever `dmesg` outputs `AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0xd impl SATA mode` (see UPD). Also `hdparm` outputs `Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)`. Why the sata link capability is of 3.0 Gbps?

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and provide more exact information about the hardware, such as the exact laptop model, with CPU information.

Answer (score 2):

First of all look for software on the manufacturer's website.
In my case I have the drive intel s3700 
I install software called:

> Intel® SSD Data Center Tool (Intel® SSD DCT)

At the moment I'm doing this from under Windows 8.1 but similarly it should be on linux

run command line / terminal from admin rights and browsing where my drive is:

**isdct show -intelssd 0**

```
    C:\Windows\system32>isdct show -intelssd 0

- Intel SSD DC S3700 Series BTTVxxxxxxxxxxxxx -

DevicePath : \\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0
DeviceStatus : Healthy
Firmware : 5DV12270
FirmwareUpdateAvailable : The selected Intel SSD contains current firmware as of
 this tool release.
Index : 0
ModelNumber : INTEL SSDSC2BA400G3
ProductFamily : Intel SSD DC S3700 Series
SerialNumber : BTTVxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Fix the speed of the disk

**isdct set -intelssd 0 physpeed=6**

```
C:\Windows\system32>isdct set -intelssd 0 physpeed=6
Set PhySpeed successful. Please power cycle the device.
```

restart the system and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the dmesg output, it tells you that the max speed of the SATA link on ports 1 and 3 of the controller, is 3.0 Gbps, which comes out to a theoretical max speed of about 357 MB/s. For an advertised max read speed of 6.0 Gbps, the theroetical max read speed of about 750 MB/s, getting 280 MB/s on a 3.0 Gbps controller is doing pretty well.

Comment: `dmesg` outputs `AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0xd impl SATA mode` (see UPD). Also `hdparm` outputs `Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)`. Why the max speed of the SATA link on 3 is 3.0Gb/s?

Comment: Perhaps because you have both the mSATA and a 2.5" SATA installed, and so the controller must drop speed to half to support both, due to PCIe lane configuration? If you unplug one, do you then see full 6.0 Gbps for the attached port?

Comment: I've unpluged the other SATA drives (HDD and optical) and got the same results for `dsmeg` and `smartctl`. So, I reformulated the second question **"How can I identify the device (SSD/port/something) reducing the resulting speed?"**