# How to enable 6Gbps for SATA3?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, sata

Though it supports SATA Rev 3.0, still there is no Gen3 listed here? Tried to set the speed using "libata.force=6.0Gbps", but getting error like "ata: failed to parse force parameter "6.0Gbps" (unknown value)".

```
~ # hdparm -I /dev/sda | egrep "Model|speed|Transport"
        Model Number:       TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100V -63
        Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
~ #

~ # smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.1, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
~ #
```

Why its not showing the capability as 6.0 Gb/s here? Why I am unable to set the speed forcibly? Or is there anything else need to be enabled?

Comment: Toshiba page says: "Interface: SATA 3.3 Gbit/s". It's a hardware issue.